# Read characters from a file. C language

Tags: c

This is the file.

```
X   1   0   1
1   X   X   1
1   0   1   0

1   1   0   X
0   X   1   1
1   X   1   0
```

This is my code.. Version 1.

```
char cha2[1];
int patternStored[180];
for(a=0;a<(numberOfPatterns*12);a++)
    {
        fscanf(patternMatFile,"%1s",cha2);
        if(cha2[0]=='X')
        {
            patternStored[a]=2;
        }
        else
        {
            patternStored[a]=atoi(cha2);
        }
    }
```

The purpose of the code is to read a single character at a time and save it into the array
the above code works fine but..

at the end of the loop, i am having this error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cha2' was corrupted.
```

This is the second version.

```
char cha[4];
int patternStored[180];
for(a=0;a<(numberOfPatterns*12);a++)
    {
        fscanf(patternMatFile,"%c",cha);
        if(cha[0]=='X')
        {
            patternStored[a]=2;
        }
        else
        {
            patternStored[a]=atoi(cha);
        }
    }
```

The second version doesn't have error. But it only works with `%d`.. only digits..

I actually doesn't know the proper way to get a single character from file using `fscanf`, especially the `%` thing.

Tkz..

Comment: When reading from a file, `fscanf` is almost never the answer. `fgets` / `sscanf` is almost always better, and usually there's an even better way than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a char, you'll want to use `%c`.

Comment: I used `%c` instead of `%1s` in version 1. There is no error. Yes, that's great. And I put a break at the end of the loop and check my integer array and it is haveing `-858993460` except the first one. I traced for the first 5 times. and only the first 5 values are in it. is it normal or sth wrong??